# Patio roof posts are deforming

Tags: wood, patio, pressure-treated

[image]

A few weeks ago, I replaced my rotten patio roof posts with pressure treated 4x4s.

Now, they are starting to deform. One bent in a U-shape, the other one is bending like an accordion under the weight.

Any idea what could have gone wrong? Did I use the wrong wood?

Comment: 4x4s can hold/withstand a lot of weight.  Your patio roof does not use ten inch thick cement pad does it?  It might happen if it was green unseasoned wood that is warping.

Comment: It sits on a concrete slab which is about 10” thick. The wood is pressure treated, the brown ones.

Comment: What size was doing the job previously?

Comment: Need to know what type of patio roof to have an idea of the weight, but doubt if that is the problem.

Comment: Most likely the wood was "green" -- not dried completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture of the whole patio roof & post structure would be helpful, but it's likely that it's just what's been noted in the comments - *very* wet pressure treated lumber starting to dry and warping under the stress of holding up the roof.

Usually, you can return warped lumber to the store, so I'd recommend doing so. Of course, you can't just pull the posts, leaving the roof hanging in the air while you run them back, so you'll need to work something out. (Check out the Note: at the bottom.)

At a minimum, you'll want to buy new posts and let them sit on the concrete (so they're level), with some thin boards underneath them to allow for air flow (1x1, 1x2, scraps of whatever you have laying around, they're called stickers), and let the posts dry for several weeks, possibly as much as 3 months.

By laying flat with no stress on them, they *should* dry flat and straight, but warping can always occur. It's just the nature of wood - some will warp a lot, some a little, some almost not at all.

Then, replace these posts with your newly dried posts, and you should be good to go.

Note: You may have to get these posts returned before your new lumber dries out. If so, you can make some temporary supports for the roof out of untreated 2x4 lumber to hold it up while there are no supports. I did something similar when I had to completely rebuild my wooden front porch, but not the roof. I had it temporarily supported for about a month while we did the construction underneath. It's a common thing and nothing to worry about. Watch some videos (be careful whose advice you take from YouTube, there are some idiots out there) from reputable sources (*This Old House* is a good one) on building a temporary roof support.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think that's what my issue was. The wood was definitely still damp when I installed it. I do have steel supports, so I'm going to use those.